# What happens to the swap partition after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: upgrade, swap

Will the swap partition be utilized to become part of an ext4 filesystem? If not, how will the swap space be utilized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you'll only get swap file

1. if you're doing a clean install, and
2. you're not using LVM

If you're upgrading from a previous version to 17.*, your swap drive will stay and work the same. [More on this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/12/ubuntu-17-04-drops-swaps-swap-partitions-swap-files).